# Arithmetic progression - terms divisible by a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> If $p$ is a prime and $p \nmid b$, prove that in the arithmetic progression $a, a+b, a +2b, $ $a+3b, \ldots$, every $p^{th}$ term is divisible by $p$.

I am given the hint that because $\gcd(p,b)=1$, there exist integers $r$ and $s$ satisfying $pr+bs=1$.  Put $n_k$ = $kp-as$ for $k = 1,2,...$ and show that $p \mid a + n_k b$.

I get how to solve the problem once I apply the hint, but I am unsure how to prove the hint.  How do I know what to set $n_k$ to?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find $r$ and $s$.

Suppose $p=31$, $b=23$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
pr+bs & r & s \\
\hline p=31 & 1 & 0 \\
b=23 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
8 & 1 & -1 \\
7 & -2 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & -4 \\
\end{array}$$

$31\cdot 3 + 23 \cdot -4 = 93-92 = 1 \quad \checkmark$

The process works by, at each step, subtracting a multiple of the last line from the line above it to get a smaller number. So $23-2\times 8 = 7$, for example, and the same operations are applied to the $r$ and $s$ values.

---

Then looking at $n_k=kp-as$, we see that
$\begin{align}a+n_kb &= a+bkp-bas \\
&= a+bkp-a(1-rp) \\
&= a+bkp-a+arp \\
&= p(bk+ar)\\
\end{align}$

and so $p\mid a{+}n_kb$ as required. Note that successive values of $n_k$ are different by exactly $p$ to complete the proof.

Comment: May you explain me why n(k)=kp-as? I have been trying to solve this problem but I am lost. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! One silly question. Why n(k)=kp-as? I do not understand that.

Comment: $kp$ allows you to talk each $p^{th}$ element, and $-as$ allows you to move to the correct starting point since $s\equiv b^{-1} \bmod p$ ie. $s$ is the inverse of $b \bmod p$

Comment: Thank you for your help! You wrote "Note that successive values of n(k) are different by exactly p to complete the proof." May you explain that? Also, the problem uses the expression pth term. I am still lost about that. However, I love you explanation that s in the inverse of b mod p.

Comment: The question asks us to show that "every $p^{th}$ term is divisible by $p$.", so we need to find a way of shifting from one term to another $p$ terms later, which is what $kp$ does in $n_k=kp-as$

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hint: define 
$$
f(n) \equiv_p \prod_{j=n}^{n+p-1} (a+bj)
$$

as $(b,p)=1$ we can find an integer $k$ such that $kb \equiv _p 1$. thus (using *Fermat's Little Theorem* for the second step)
$$
kf(n) \equiv_p k^p f(n) \equiv_p k^p\prod_{j=n}^{n+p-1} (a+bj) \equiv_p \prod_{j=n}^{n+p-1} (ka+j) \equiv_p 0
$$
since the product of any $p$ consecutive integers must be divisible by $p$

Comment: May you explain me why n(k)=kp-as? I have been trying to solve this problem but I am lost. Thank you for your help!

Comment: the method i used here is different, and the proof as it stands is incomplete. but as to your question, in the hint OP mentions $n_k$ is defined that way because it gives a constructive solution. have a more careful look at the last part of Joffan's answer. good luck!